# How to interpret TLC data regarding the purity of one’s sample

Tags: experimental-chemistry, chromatography

The picture provided is a sketch of my TLC data from the lab along with the $R_f$ values for $i$ (initial, un-recrystallized aspirin) $= 0.429$, $a$ (acetylsalicylic acid) $= 0.429$, and $s$ (salicylic acid) $= 0.571$.

One of the questions in my post lab was:

> Based on the TLC data, discuss the purity of the impure aspirin sample, explain your reasoning.

So far, I have said that based on the data, the aspirin sample would be considered pure because there were no multiple spots in any lane. I don't know how else to elaborate on this. What can I say about the $R_f$ values?

[image]

Comment: If that is an accurate rendering of the TLC slide, I agree with your conclusion.

Comment: If your picture is in any way accurate then no way can the solvent front be 3.5 cm while salicylic acid is 2.0 cm.

Answer (score 2):

TLC is a great and poor method at the same time. It is great because it is quick and accurate, and it is poor because it can only show substances that can be coloured in some way and are sufficiently non-volatile to not evaporate away.

You can be rather sure of the following points:

1. Your impure sample does not contain any more free acid since a spot of the same $R_f$ value is missing.
2. Your impure sample contains a probably very high amount of aspirin, since the spot has the same $R_f$ value.

However, you cannot be sure about:

1. Impurities that evaporated away during spotting, development or colouring of the TLC plate
2. Impurities that simply don’t show up in your method of colouring (e.g. due to the lack of a benzene ring for UV fluorescence).
3. Solvent impurities that will never show up due to both points above.

To prove purity you would need to resort to different analytic methods such as melting point (historically), HPLC-MS or GC-MS, NMR, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If "i" is the "impure" aspirin sample, then yes. Both the aspirin and the acetylsalicylic acid have the same retention factor of 0.429. This shows that the impure aspirin sample contains acetylsalicylic acid. As you stated, the absence of any other spots in the TLC shows that the impure aspirin sample only contains acetylsalicylic acid. Therefore, it is pure.

In the real world, however, it is more complicated. Retention factors are not a definitive indicator. Many compounds can have similar (and even identical) retention factors.  Hence, it is theoretically possible that a compound with Rf value of 0.429 that is not aspirin is mixed with it. Furthermore, the retention factors change depending on the conditions (choice of mobile phase, stationary phase, temperature, etc). Thus, it is necessary to further analyze it with mass spectrometers, etc. And also to carefully adjust the conditions.

But for a chemistry lab, your reasoning should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

An old school method is to make up known concentrations of the reference material and standardise the spotting method. The spot size was then used to approximate a concentration and give a purity range